# How to port the SharePoint project from development server to client server?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

Our team is developing a SharePoint 2010 project. The project contains some workflows developed in SharePoint Designer. And there are workflows developed in visual studio 2010.

For workflow developed in visual studio I would get a .wsp package which I can deploy at the server farm.

But I don't understand how to deploy the workflows created with SharePoint Designer 2010 as I don't have any solution package file.

Comment: Are your workflows from SharePoint Designer reusable workflows?

Comment: Yes. We have developed reusable workflows.

Comment: In that case you can do as Per just said, as I was going to :/
Also see http://www.oriolardevol.com/Article/Details/Move%20a%20Sharepoint%20Designer%20Workflow%20to%20a%20different%20Farm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your workflow is a "truely" reusable workflow then you can get a wsp by:

1. Open SharePoint Designer on the Development server
2. Open the Site with the Workflow
3. In navigation select workflows
4. Select your workflow
5. Click "Save as template" in the ribbon
6. Go to "Site Assets" in the site
7. Download the generated wsp

Unfortunately it's very easy to make a resuable workflow not "truely" resuable by refering to specific lists, which will include the GUID of these into the workflow. If your workflow isn't "truely" resuable then you may get help from: [Deploy SharePoint Designer 2010 Reusable Workflow As *.WSP File](http://dmitrygusev.blogspot.dk/2010/11/deploy-sharepoint-designer-2010.html)

Comment: Actually the workflow is associated with custom content type. So will I have to create content type at client server ?

Comment: Yes you'll have to create that content type and custom site columns (if any) with the same IDs as in development. It's fairly easy to use Server Explorer or SharePoint manager to get the XML of these and add to a Visual Studio project